# How to append to a line in a file in reverse?

Tags: python

Given this code:

```
for num in range(10):
    with open("append_reverse.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(str(num)+ ', ')
```

I want that the last element appended to the file is always on the first line. Eg:
Output: `9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0`

Comment: You just changed the code completely. That is not how the site works. If you have a different question, please create a new post. I will rollback your edit.

Comment: What is your `datiLog` class supposed to do? What is its `Write()` method? This is very hard to understand. Please read [ask] and try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please take notice of what @HarshalParekh said. Changing the question completely is unfair on people who have already answered your original question.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I won't do it anymore. I didn't want to break the rules, I'm just new on the site. Thanks a lot alaniwi and Harshal to have pointed it out to me

Answer (score 1):

Use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed).

```
nums = list()
for i in reversed(range(10)):
    nums.append(str(i))

with open("append_reverse.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write(','.join(nums))
```

Comment: This will open and write to the file 10 times. A lot of unnecessary I/O.

Comment: @HarshalParekhThe question wasn't how to optimize but how to reverse the numbers. That's why I just copied the code and pasted as-is.

Comment: Does that mean you will not even mention the other mistakes? This is not a site just to solve problems. It is a site to learn how to become a better programmer.

Comment: Updated my answer with an optimized solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop and use the `join` method, this way you won't get a comma in the end of the string. `reversed` to revert the `range` and `map` to convert every element of the reversed range to strings.

```
with open("append_reverse.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write(','.join(map(str, reversed(range(10)))))
```

Comment: I'd assume the OP is new to coding. So I'd also add an example with loops for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
with open("append_reverse.txt", "a") as file:
  for num in range(9,0,-1):
    file.write(str(num) + ', ')
  file.write(str(0))
```

I wrote the `0` apart because you didn't write a `,`  after it.
If you do want the comma, you could do

```
with open("append_reverse.txt", "a") as file:
  for num in range(9,-1,-1):
    file.write(str(num) + ', ')
```